# At which point does an exploit against TAILS happen?

Tags: exploit, tor

Since TAILS by default disallows root/superuser privileges and since traffic is sent encrypted with each relay removing a layer until the exit node, at what point is an exploit on a version of TAILS with known vulnerabilities happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical sequence is remote code execution exploit followed by sandbox escape and privilege escalation.

First, the attacker would have to be able to run code inside Tails. This is possible through remote code execution if there is a vulnerability in Tails which allows this:

- Exploiting a vulnerability in a browser or libraries using it can be exploited if the user visits a website exploiting this vulnerability. It is exploited by triggering the browser into downloading and viewing (image/media) or executing (javascript) the crafted exploit, which allows the attacker to execute arbitrary code on your machine by triggering a known vulnerability. There are many possibilities - vulnerabilities in image parsers, in Javascript engine, in HTML parser, in various audio or video formats, and so on.
- Exploiting a vulnerability in other networking components used by Tails (such as NTP client which is used for time synchronization). An attacker who learns about the vulnerability in the NTP client, and can gain control over the relevant NTP server, can trigger this vulnerability remotely and without any user interaction. Same for exploiting a vulnerability in Tor client itself.

Once the attacker gained code execution on a system (even under limited privileges and without superuser), the attacker can attempt try to use  other type of exploits, such as privilege escalation exploits, to gain privileges in the system. And depending on attacker's goal it might not even be necessary to gain privileges.

So, as you see, exploits can happen at many points, and are not limited to a single point.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Would [these symptoms](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/sudden-spike-in-received-traffic-when-connecting-to-the-tor-network) be indicative of the latter types of attacks?

Comment: Possibly, although unlikely - there are probably other explanations for the spike.

Comment: Can you tell me what other things I can try looking at to get a clue?